# How to update ruby version on digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have ruby version 2.2.1 install on digital ocean live server, now i want to update ruby to latest version without affecting my live poject.

Comment: Make sure you don't use deprecated Ruby features, SSH into the server, update Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Use following command

```
sudo apt-get install ruby(your ruby version) rubygems(your ruby version)
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/ruby(your ruby version)/usr/bin/ruby
```